# can't set jQuery DatePicker to specific date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

i'm designing a form which takes passengers' information. i need their birth dates so i'm using datepicker tool.

here is my code:

```
 $('#datepickerBirth').datepicker({
            inline: true,
            changeYear: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            dateFormat: 'MM dd, yy',
            showOtherMonths: true
        });
        $("#datepickerBirth").datepicker("setDate", "10/12/1986");
```

code works well but not the date. it shows january 12,2019 when i run project. but i set my date to another one. where am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#datepickerBirth').datepicker("setDate", new Date(1986,10,12) );
```

Answer (score 1):

The new date may be a Date object or a string in the current date format - your format is 'MM dd, yy'

```
var myDate = new Date(1986,10,12) 
$('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', myDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
var myDate = new Date(1986,12,10);
$('#datepicker').datepicker();
$('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', myDate);
});
```

Try it like this